# Google Book API + While searching only show 10 books - How to increase those count

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, google-books

In my project, I am trying to display google books using google book api, but issue is like api renders only ten books at at time.

At least, I need 50 books while searching but I am not able to get 50 books.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=technology
```

Output recevied :

```
{
 "kind": "books#volumes",
 "totalItems": 861,
 "items": []
}
```

it shows that total items searched = 861 but shows only 10.

Any advice. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Suddenly while searching, I found one key point and I got the answer.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=technology&maxResults=40
```

As per the requirement, we have to add `&maxResults`

But google added one condition while searching about the limitation of books list ie maximum result has to be less than 40

```
"message": "Invalid value '41'. Values must be within the range: [0, 40]",
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Rajarshi Babu